# send the request to take(transfer) the bid price without any confirmation from the bidder when the seller accept the bid offer

Tags: ether, metamask, ethers.js, ethereumjs, nextjs

When an NFT seller attempts to sell their NFT using the "sell to the highest bid" option on OpenSea, and a bidder tries to place a bid, the price value set by the bidder will not be transferred to the seller until the seller accepts the bid offer. Similarly, I want to send a confirmation to the bidder when they try to place a bid, informing them that they don't need to send the transaction now. The transfer will be done automatically when the seller accepts the bid offer. How can I achieve this with Ethers.js?

i want this functionalities in my project .

```
    function placeBid(uint256 _tokenId,uint256 _bidPrice) public payable {
    require(nftDetails[_tokenId].inAuction, "Auction not in progress");
    require(_bidPrice > nftDetails[_tokenId].basePrice,"Bid price is lower than base price");
    require(msg.value > nftDetails[_tokenId].highestBid, "Bid must be higher than current highest bid");

    if (nftDetails[_tokenId].highestBidder != address(0)) {
        payable(nftDetails[_tokenId].highestBidder).transfer(nftDetails[_tokenId].highestBid);
    }

    // Update highest bid and bidder
    nftDetails[_tokenId].highestBid = msg.value;
    nftDetails[_tokenId].highestBidder = msg.sender;

    emit placedBid(msg.sender, _tokenId, block.timestamp, msg.value);
}
```

when the owner(seller) accept the offer the the bid price should transfer from the bidder to the seller .

what i mean is how to do that with ethers and metamask . to send the request to take(transition) the bid price without any confirmation from the bidder when the seller accept the bid offer.

In my frontend

```
    const placeBid = async(contractAddress:any)=>{
  try {
    const provider = await new ethers.BrowserProvider((window as any).ethereum);
    await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
    const signers = await provider.getSigner();
    if (signers) {
      const contractInstance = new ethers.Contract(
        contractAddress,
        contractAbi,
        signers
      );
      // How to send the request ???
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

If any one know this please help.